# How to avoid having too much managed code in Spring

Tags: spring, unit-testing, dependency-injection

In the app I'm working on, every class is managed by the Spring container and each one of them has a separate interface.

95% of the those beans have a single implementation. So almost every class is duplicated - an interface and an implementation.

Most of the time this is due to transitive management:

Class A1 uses class A2 uses class A3... all the way to A6. A1 and A6 are managed.

In order for A5 to get an instance of A6, it must be managed.

So we make A5 managed too. Repeat this process for A4, A3 and A2 and you get 4 classes that don't really need to be managed but they are because somewhere down below there is a managed bean.

It is possible to keep A2..A5 not managed and in A5 use the application context to get an instance of A6 but Spring docs urge against it.

My question is, is Spring DI an all-or-nothing approach, or is there a good way to mix managed and non managed code?

Why is it so bad to use the application context to get beans?

Is there a good way to unit test managed code that uses non managed code?

Comment: Why would there be a performance hit for using `@Autowired` it would only matter for startup times but that would be it. Using interfaces makes you also think about the contract you expose the the outside world. Because that is what the interface is, your contract and changing a contract should be (somewhat) painful. Also why would everything have to be a managed bean? A managed bean is no different as an EJB and normal OO principals still apply. Spring isn't something magical that changes everything.

Comment: Yes, the hit is on startup times. It takes a lot of time to run an integration test and even much more to run the full suite. Regarding your second question, I'll edit my question to explain.

Comment: Why would you need to wire everything for an integration test, you can only wire the things you need (use a custom configuration for that). If your full suite takes a long time to load you probably want to take a look at your tests. In general (when configured properly and using spring-test support) the configuration is loaded once and reused so it should be a hit once and not for each test.

Comment: Yes, you can wire just what you need. But I find it very hard and time consuming to do that. If you only need a tiny context, it is ok. But let's leave the question of performance aside for now. I am more interested in the big picture. Is it really a good idea to make everything managed? I mean, what is the ROI on that considering most of the classes inside the same jar are pretty coupled anyway? It's not like we treat every single class in the application as a library, most of them are internal to the application.

Comment: I still don't see the difference with an EJB and the fact that you think that everything needs to be managed? You can still use new to construct classes if you need, you don't have to inject the whole world. Not sure where you got that idea from...

Comment: First, thanks for your time, appreciate it. I think I understand my problem better now, please see my edited question.